# One filter is reseting the other. can't apply both of them

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using 2 filters on one image. The problem is simple to understand, if I'll move one slider the filter will apply fine but when I'll move the other slider the picture will reset to the original `_tempImage`.
I've tried replacing  `_justNowImage.image = quickFilteredImage;` with `_tempImage = quickFilteredImage;` but the result is a filter that is going crazy.

Thanks

```
   - (IBAction)sharpenSliderChanged:(id)sender
    {   
        GPUImageSharpenFilter *sharpenFilter = [[GPUImageSharpenFilter alloc] init];
        [sharpenFilter setSharpness:sharpenSlider.value];
        UIImage *quickFilteredImage = [sharpenFilter imageByFilteringImage: _tempImage];
        _justNowImage.image = quickFilteredImage;
    }

    - (IBAction)exposureSliderChanged:(id)sender
    {
        GPUImageExposureFilter *exposureFilter = [[GPUImageExposureFilter alloc] init];
        [exposureFilter setExposure:exposureSlider.value];
        UIImage *quickFilteredImage = [exposureFilter imageByFilteringImage: _tempImage];
        _justNowImage.image = quickFilteredImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    UIImage *quickFilteredImage = [exposureFilter imageByFilteringImage: _tempImage];
```

**you are applying different filter to the original image only ..i.e** `_tempImage`

add these lines to end of both methods

```
_tempImage = quickFilteredImage
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, that messes up the filter and it is not working as it should.

Comment: you need to set _tempImage = quickFilteredImage after user has done the slider change...some other control event..probably touch down exit